# Prefetch and multiprocessing in Torch Geometric Dataset

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm using Torch Geometric `Dataset` to process and load dataset for my ML model training. Basically, I want to do something like `num_parallel_calls` (for multiprocessing) and `.prefetch()` (to process the next batch of data in CPU while training is done in GPU) like in `tf.data.Dataset` [here](https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/datapipeline/#best-practices) using torch geometric [Dataset](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_dataset.html). How can we do that? What I understand so far `__getitem__` or `get()` only loads 1 file at a time. Thank you